# How to write these mongo code in go

Tags: go, mgo

> **My mongo File is here**

```
 db.aaa.aggregate([{
                $match : {
                    status : "Active"
                }
            }, {
                $project : {
                    _id : 1,
                    title : 1,
                    postdatetime : 1,
                    status : 1,
                    answer : {
                        $filter : {
                            input : "$answer",
                            as : "answe",
                            cond : {
                                $eq : ["$$answe.status", "Active"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
```

> **I try this one to write in go**

```
o2 := bson.M{
    "$project":bson.M{
        "$answer":bson.M{
                "_id":1,"title":1,"postdatetime":1,"status":1,"answer":bson.M{
                            "$filter":bson.M{"input":"$answer","as":"ans","cond":bson.M{"$eq":bson.M["$$ans.status","Active",],},}
                        },

            },
        },
}
```

> > But it show this on err
> >      **syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting ]**
>
> Please Help me Out.
>
> ```
> After the answer i try this one
> ```

```
   o2: = bson.M {
    "$project": bson.M {
        "$answer": bson.M {
            "_id": 1,
            "title": 1,
            "revision": 1,
            "bgimageurl": 1,
            "author": 1,
            "postdatetime": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "qatags": 1,
            "followers": 1,
            "qaviews": 1,
            "answer": bson.M {
                "$filter": bson.M {
                    "input": "$answer",
                    "as": "ans",
                    "cond": bson.M {
                        "$eq": "[$$ans.status][,Active]",
                    },
                },
            },

        },
    },
}
```

> This time compile successfully but after running the go file send me this err msg  **2016/05/11 11:04:17 $expressions are not allowed at the top-level of $project
>   exit status 1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

#### 1. Array in bson.M

`bson.M["$$ans.status","Active",]` will give you error like `Type bson.M is not an expression`, and since you are not required key-value pair in this case, an array of string would be a preferable case.

Try:

```
[]string{"$$ans.status","Active",}
```

#### 2. The comma

According to https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html:

> the lexer always inserts a semicolon after the token. This could be summarized as, “if the newline comes after a token that could end a statement, insert a semicolon”.

If you are not appended a comma after `}`, lexer will insert a `;` for you, which will cause your current problem.

```
"$filter":bson.M{"input":"$answer","as":"ans","cond":bson.M{"$eq":bson.M{"$$ans.status","Active",},},} // should add a comma at the end of the line
```

After modified:

```
"$filter":bson.M{"input":"$answer","as":"ans","cond":bson.M{"$eq":[]string{"$$ans.status","Active",},},},
```

#### Update

For your second question, `$expressions are not allowed at the top-level of $project`, please note that aggregation in `mongodb` only accept `array`, you can refer to this link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { <stage> }, ... ] )
```

Comment: I try this one o2: = bson.M {
 "$project": bson.M {
  "$answer": bson.M {
   "_id": 1,
   "title": 1,
   "revision": 1,
   "bgimageurl": 1,
   "author": 1,
   "postdatetime": 1,
   "status": 1,
   "qatags": 1,
   "followers": 1,
   "qaviews": 1,
   "answer": bson.M {
    "$filter": bson.M {
     "input": "$answer",
     "as": "ans",
     "cond": bson.M {
      "$eq": bson.M {
       "$$ans.status",
       "Active",
      },
     },
    },
   },

  },
 },
}

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated my answer some minutes ago

Comment: I also try this one o2: = bson.M {
 "$project": bson.M {
  "$answer": bson.M {
   "_id": 1,
   "title": 1,
   "revision": 1,
   "bgimageurl": 1,
   "author": 1,
   "postdatetime": 1,
   "status": 1,
   "qatags": 1,
   "followers": 1,
   "qaviews": 1,
   "answer": bson.M {
    "$filter": bson.M {
     "input": "$answer",
     "as": "ans",
     "cond": bson.M {
      "$eq": bson.M["$$ans.status", "Active", ],
     },
    },
   },

  },
 },
}

Comment: it give me error syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting ]

Comment: Ops, I have updated my first answer but not the second, this code will back to the `Array` problem that I have mentioned, try to use `[]string{"$$ans.status","Active",}` as I mentioned in first part. I will update the second part too.

Comment: And after all, I would suggest you to start from simple query, eg, you should make sure your `$project` query is working before proceed to nested query, and also take note that `aggregation` need an `array`...

Comment: after use this one o2 := bson.M{
  "$project":bson.M{
   "$answer":bson.M{
     "_id":1,"title":1,"revision":1,"bgimageurl":1,"author":1,"postdatetime":1,"status":1,"qatags":1,"followers":1,"qaviews":1,"answer":bson.M{
        "$filter":bson.M{"input":"$answer","as":"ans","cond":bson.M{"$eq":[]string{"$$ans.status","Active",},},},
       },
      
    },
   },
 }

Comment: error is $expressions are not allowed at the top-level of $project
exit status 1

Comment: As mentioned in answer... `aggregation` need `array`, a simple way to do it is wrap your `o2` into an array: `someName := []bson.M{o2}`

Answer (score 2):

> After doing all this one is working

```
o2 := bson.M{
        "$project":bson.M{"_id":1,"title":1,"postdatetime":1,"status":1"answer":bson.M{
                    "$filter":bson.M{"input":"$answer","as":"ans","cond":bson.M{"$eq":[]string{"$$ans.status","Active",},},},},},}
```